# how to parse a list to get a value

Tags: python

I need some ideas on how to parse a list and print a specific value,Lets say I want to parse dependsontext and then just print the number "249452",please suggest ideas

```
INPUT:-

dependsontext = [{u'isCurrentPatchSet': True, u'revision': u'ad0beef66e5890cde6f0961ed03d8bc7e3defc63', u'ref': u'refs/changes/52/249452/1', u'id': u'Iad0beef66e5890cde6f0961ed03d8bc7e3defc63', u'number': u'249452'}]

OUTPUT:-

249452
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: You have a dict (in a list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since you used the python tag, it looks like you want

```
dependsontext[0]['number']
```

`dependsontext` is a one-element list of dictionaries, so you can get the first element with `[0]`
Then you can retrieve a value from that dictionary with a key, like `['number']`

Your question is a bit unclear though - it's hard to tell if you're using python data structures or strings. If it's the latter, I'd recommend looking at the simplejson module for json parsing.